# Pass document content from one screen to another in flutter firestore

Tags: flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

In the code below, I am trying to pass data from the home screen to the detail screen when user clicks on any of the product listed on the home screen. I seem to be having difficulty here.

[Similar Question but does not solve my issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60876728/how-do-i-pass-a-single-firestore-document-id-to-another-class-based-on-a-selecti)

**Excerpt of the code at the home screen.**

```
                  StreamBuilder(
                  stream: FirebaseFirestore.instance
                      .collection("name")
                      .limit(12)
                      .orderBy("Published Date", descending: true)
                      .snapshots(),
                  builder: (context, snapshot){
                    if (!snapshot.hasData) {
                      return Center(
                        child: spinkit,
                      );
                    }
                    return GridView.builder(
                        physics: ScrollPhysics(),
                        scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
                        shrinkWrap: true,
                        itemCount: snapshot.data.docs.length,
                        gridDelegate: SliverGridDelegateWithFixedCrossAxisCount(
                          crossAxisCount: 3,
                          crossAxisSpacing: 10.0,
                          mainAxisSpacing: 10,
                          
                        ),
                        itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index){
                          if(snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting){
                            return Center(
                              child: spinkit,
                            );
                          }
                          print("${snapshot.data.documents[index].get('Product Title')}");
                          return GestureDetector(
                            onTap: (){
                              // ===> SEND USER TO THE DETAILS SCREEN <===
                              Navigator.push(
                                context,
                                MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => ProductDetailsScreen()),
                              );
                            },
                            child: ClipRRect(
                              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(5),
                              child: Stack(
                                children: [
                                  Container(
                                    height: 150,
                                    width: 150,
                                    child: Image.network(
                                      snapshot.data.documents[index].get('image') ?? spinkit,
                                      fit: BoxFit.cover,
                                      width: double.infinity,
                                      height: double.infinity,
                                    ),
                                  ),
                                  Positioned(
                                    left: 0,
                                    bottom: 0,
                                    child: Container(
                                      height: 20,
                                      width: 150,
                                      decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                          gradient: LinearGradient(
                                            colors: [
                                              Colors.black38,
                                              Colors.black38,
                                            ],
                                            begin: Alignment.bottomCenter,
                                            end: Alignment.topCenter,
                                          )),
                                    ),
                                  ),
                                  Positioned(
                                    left: 4,
                                    bottom: 5,
                                    child: Text(
                                      snapshot.data.documents[index].get('name') ?? "Product Name",
                                      overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
                                      style: TextStyle(
                                          color: Palette.whiteColor,
                                          fontSize: 11,
                                          fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                                    ),
                                  )
                                ],
                              ),
                            ),
                          );
                        }
                    );
                  },
                )
```

**And excerpt of the code at the Details Screen. what you see at the detail screen is data that I have populated manually. it is not coming from firestore.**

```
class ProductDetailsScreen extends StatefulWidget {

  @override
  _ProductDetailsScreenState createState() => _ProductDetailsScreenState();
}

class _ProductDetailsScreenState extends State<ProductDetailsScreen> {

  final productDb = FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection("name");

  User user = FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser;

  final spinkit = SpinKitHourGlass(
    color: Colors.white,
    size: 50.0,
  );

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return WillPopScope(
      onWillPop: _onBackPressed,
      child: Scaffold(
        body: SafeArea(
            child: Padding(
              padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 15, right: 15, top: 3, bottom: 10),
              child: FutureBuilder(
                future: productDb.get(),
                builder: (context, snapshot){
                  if(snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting){
                    return Center(
                      child: spinkit,
                    );
                  }
                  return Container(
                    child: ListView(
                      children: [
                        Column(
                          children: [
                            Center(
                              child: Container(
                                width: 350,
                                child: Card(
                                  elevation: 5,
                                  child: Container(
                                    padding: EdgeInsets.all(8),
                                    child: Container(
                                      height: 220,
                                      decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                          image: DecorationImage(
                                              fit: BoxFit.fill,
                                              image: AssetImage("asset/images/headphone.jpg",)
                                          )
                                      ),
                                    ),
                                  ),
                                ),
                              ),
                            ),
                            SizedBox(height: 10,),
                            Row(
                              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                              children: [
                                Text("Item Name",
                                  style: TextStyle(
                                      color: Palette.blackColor,
                                      fontSize: 18,
                                      fontWeight: FontWeight.w300
                                  ),),
                                Text("Item Price",
                                  style: TextStyle(
                                      color: Palette.blackColor,
                                      fontSize: 18,
                                      fontWeight: FontWeight.w300
                                  ),),
                              ],
                            ),
                            SizedBox(height: 10,),
                            Text("Item Description",
                              style: TextStyle(
                                  color: Palette.blackColor,
                                  fontSize: 18,
                                  fontWeight: FontWeight.w300
                              ),),
                            Container(
                              height: 1,
                              width: 100,
                              color: Colors.black12,
                            ),
                            SizedBox(height: 10,),
                            Container(
                              height: 140,
                              width: 350,
                              child: SingleChildScrollView(
                                child: Wrap(
                                    children: [
                                      Text(
                                        "What is Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy "
                                            "text of the printing and typesetting industry"
                                            " Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard"
                                            " dummy text ever since the 1500s when an "
                                            "unknown printer took a galley of type and "
                                            "scrambled it to make a type specimen book "
                                            "it has?",
                                        textAlign: TextAlign.justify,
                                        style: TextStyle(
                                          color: Palette.blackColor,
                                          fontSize: 16,
                                        ),),
                                    ]
                                ),
                              ),
                            ),
                          ],
                        ),
                      ],
                    ),
                  );
                },
              ),
            )),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your `GestureDetector` `onTap`

```
// ===> SEND USER TO THE DETAILS SCREEN WITH DOC<===
Navigator.push(
  context,
  MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => ProductDetailsScreen(snapshot.data.documents[index])),
);
```

Then

```
class ProductDetailsScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  ProductDetailsScreen(this.doc);

  QueryDocumentSnapshot doc;

  @override
  _ProductDetailsScreenState createState() => _ProductDetailsScreenState();
}
```

Access in `_ProductDetailsScreenState` as `widget.doc`.

The document data will be found at `widget.doc.data` as a `Map<String, dynamic>`.

Comment: Thanks for your response. After implementing your suggestion in the ProductDetailsScreen, it I am getting Document isn't defined error. @Lee3

Comment: My apologies. I did not recall the class names off the top of my head. The answer has been updated.